# How to do styling on HTML tags contained within the <a> hyperlink tag

Tags: html, hyperlink, tags, href

I am trying to make a group of HTML tags (p, div, image) point to the same URL (e.g. www.worldwide_news.com). I also want to be able to style the text inside the P in a way I want. I have tried wrapping them all inside an '' tag, but then the text inside the P elements for example, all appear with i) Underline.. and ii) Blue in color, like they do in an 'a' tag. Also I want the whole of inside the P to be clickable (setting P to a width of 400px), not only the text bit.
I don't wanna use JAVASCRIPT or any other JQUERY or any script, I want a simple HTML solution. Would anyone please be able to help?

So far I have the following which works on clicking to the URL, but unable to style the text:

```
<a href="https://www.worldwide_news.com">
    <div style="border:1px;border-style: solid;"
        <p>Here is a link to my other blog</p>
           <img src="image.jpg">
        <p>Once you get there do leave a comment!</p>
    </div>
</a>
```

I also tried to no avail:

```
    <div style="border:1px;border-style: solid;" href="https://www.worldwide_news.com">
        <p href="https://www.worldwide_news.com">>Here is a link to my other blog</p>
           <img src="image.jpg" href="https://www.worldwide_news.com">
        <p href="https://www.worldwide_news.com">>Once you get there do leave a comment!</p>
    </div>
```

All help much appreciated! Thank you. I would send a few beers over to you but..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, in the first example, it looks like you didn't close the div tag. Try:

```
<a href="https://www.worldwide_news.com">
    <div style="border:1px; border-style:solid;">
        <p>Here is a link to my other blog</p>
           <img src="image.jpg">
        <p>Once you get there do leave a comment!</p>
    </div>
</a>
```

As for your second, I made it work, technically, but that was just by wrapping it in `<a></a>` tags. I don't think 'p href's are a thing.

Comment: Thanks @David Moore, yes p hrefs aren't really a thing, I was just trying stuff out. Managed to make it work

Answer (score 2):

Using `div` inside an `a`-tag is not strictly supported, you might want to use `span` (or nothing).

Aside from that, the only problem you have is that the default `a` styles apply to all children. If you style that with CSS (remove underline, reset colour e.g. `color: inherit`) you should get what you want. Lastly you need to set `display: block` to make it expand around the whole block.

```css
a.link {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

a.link p:first-child {
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<a class="link" href="https://example.com">
  <p>Link text one</p>
  <p>Link text two</p>
</a>
```

Comment: Hey @Consti P, thanks for that. Your suggestion worked pretty well. I am using DIV inside the 'a tag coz I have another "overall" div where I want to use "display: flex". Thats why I am using DIV's inside the 'a as well. I will try to use span as you recommended and see what comes up,

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use CSS?

**HTML**

```
<a href="https://www.worldwide_news.com">
    <div style="border:1px;border-style: solid;"
        <p class="separate-link-blue">Here is a link to my other blog</p>
           <img src="image.jpg">
        <p class="separate-link-red">Once you get there do leave a comment!</p>
    </div>
</a>
```

**CSS**

```
.separate-link-blue {
  color: blue;
}

.separate-link-red {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: Forgot a `>` end of line 2 (div)

Comment: Hi @BananaMonkey, thanks this worked. I was trying it earlier but instead of "color: red;"  was putting in "font-color: red;"  guess for the font color property didnt have to add "font-" in the css. The div does have a > at the end, just didn't paste it on here